# Create view with results in a single column in mysql

Tags: php, sql, mysql

I would like to create a view that has a single column.  If my two tables looked like the following:

Table 1:
ID  | Name
1   | Joe

Table 2:
ID  | Address
1   | 123 BlueBerry St.

The view would look like:
View:
newcolumn |
Joe
123 Blueberry St.

The reason I do this is because I have an autocomplete text box that searchs a single column with the following php / jquery code:

```
$query = $db->query("SELECT value FROM countries WHERE value LIKE '$queryString%' LIMIT 10");
if($query) {
    while ($result = $query ->fetch_object()) {
    echo '<li onClick="fill(\''.$result->value.'\');">'.$result->value.'</li>';
     }
     }
```

If there is a better way than putting all values into a single column for this solution, please let me know as well.

Comment: I know this isnt what your asking but it would be worth looking into MVC so you can start to seperate out your logic from your view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You view wouldn't be able to be searched over anyways. Do a table join and `LIKE` query on all the columns you want to match.

Like

```
SELECT value FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 USING (id) WHERE table1.col1 LIKE '%:query%' AND table2.col1 LIKE '%:query%' LIMIT 10
```

And PLEASE don't use PHP variables in your query string. Use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) instead

Comment: Thanks Paul, what column is 'value' though? I can only return one column result and I want the value of the column to be either from col1 of table1 or table2.